# Lua OpenResty testing

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

How can I mock the `ngx` object and test my Lua files?

For example, let's say I have

```
-- file.lua

function computeUpstream() 
   -- advanced calculations!
   return theCalculatedUpstream
end

ngx.var.upstream = computeUpstream()
```

And I want to test this file. How do I do that?

Comment: you can ask in openresty group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openresty-en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO the best solution is to use official [OpenResty Docker images](https://github.com/openresty/docker-openresty), run your configuration within container and test by series of HTTP request.

Using Docker (and may be docker-compose) one may simulate a whole infrastructure of tested application, mock backends, database with initial content, etc.

After some tests and tries you will find a way for good enough code coverage.